# Problems with uploading files in php

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and am trying to save files to my database. I have tried every youtube tutorial but I can't get it to work. Can someone help me maybe? I don't get any error messages either. When I click on the button nothing happens.I work with Xampp

```
   <?php 
      $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","image");
      if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
      $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $query = "INSERT INTO upload(image) VALUES ('$file')";
      $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
      if ( $res){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "$file");
      }
     }
     ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web42</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body class="background">
     
            
    <div class="logo"></div>

         <nav>
            <ul class="navbar">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li ><a href="gallery.html">Galerie</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    
        <div class="container">
          <div class="main-content">
            <h1>Lade jetzt deine Medien hoch</h1>
            <form  enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" >
              <input name="userImage" type="file" /> 
              <input type="submit" name="upload" value="submit">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVzxK.png)

Comment: Your `file` input has a name of `userImage` but you're using `$_FILES['image']`

Comment: "_When I click on the button nothing happens_" The form does not get submitted?

Comment: no.nothing is displayed in the database either

Comment: "_no_" So does it get submitted? Of course nothing shows up or the file is uploaded because you have your names wrong. See my first comment

Comment: yes it will be submitted. I habe change the name.

Comment: In the form, you used `userImage` and on php code, you used `$_FILES['image']`. Use `$_FILES['userImage']` instead. If still there is issue in executing query, change the `$res` line as `$res = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error($con));` , it will show you the error.

Comment: Just to make sure: this is all in a `.php` file (and not a `.html` one) and PHP is enabled in your server? Can you make sure to use `mysqli_connect_error`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: yes its all in the .php file :) yes its enabled

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" >
    <input name="userImage" type="file" />  <!--$_FILES['userImage'];-->
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="submit">
</form>
```

```php
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","image");
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
  $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];#$_FILES['userImage'];
  $query = "INSERT INTO upload(image) VALUES ('$file')";
  $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  if ( $res){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file);#not "$file"
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much first of all. I have corrected the points that were criticized. But still nothing is saved in the database :(